# React-Native passing props/params between children of DrawerNavigator

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have my DrawerNavigator setup as this

```
 export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
 Home:Home,
 Profile:Profile
  },{ 
  contentComponent:DrawerComponent
 })
```

The navigator itself is a child of StackNavigator.

Now, the question is how do I pass props/param between Home and Profile?

Any reading recommendation and StackOverflow answers are welcome, I didn't find anything similar to this though

Also, I am only accessing Profile from my drawer.

is redux the only way here?

Comment: just so I can understand better, you want to pass props between Home -> Profile
or from Drawer -> Home/Profile

Comment: between Home and Profile

Comment: see if this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636886/react-native-how-to-pass-props-navigating-from-one-screen-to-another

Comment: this is different if I can get access to the navigation prop of drawerNavigator where I can use setParam in Home, that will work unfortunately I couldn't make it work

using redux for now

Comment: you can pass props to a HOC, also check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694176/pass-props-through-a-higher-order-component-from-a-route